# How to check reference when inserting in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have users and roles. Each user belongs to a role. I'd like to design the database like this:

Collection Users:

```
{
    "name":"user1"
    "role":"admin"
}
```

Collection Roles:

```
{
    "name":"admin"
    "privileges":[]
}
{
    "name":"user"
    "privileges":[]
}
```

Later I could add more roles or edit privileges for any role.

My question is: when I insert a new user, how can I check if the "role" field has a valid value (that means there is a match document in the roles collection)?

Should I check this reference in the application? Is there a way to do so on mongodb server side?

Let's assume editing privilege is a frequent operation.

Comment: If you need to check it, query the collection before inserting user.

Comment: @Michelem It works but not efficient. This is done on application side. There will be two network delays for two operations. It will be better if we can do the check on mongodb server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are putting the cart before the horse.

For modeling your data, you should first now what your questions to the data are. As for a user, role and privilege relation, the question is obvious

> For a given user, what are the privileges?

As long as the privileges per role don't exceed several 100k, your role model should be rather simple

```
{
  _id: "roleName",
  description: "a role",
  privileges:[
      "someService:someAction:someInstance",
  ]
},
{
  _id: "admin",
  description: "Administrator",
  privileges:[
      "adminService:*:*",
  ]
}
```

We have a given user with the simplified model of

```
{
  _id: "foo",
  roles: ["roleName","admin"]
}
```

In order to get the privileges *for the given user "foo"* (which you have loaded before as `user`), we do something like

```
var user_privileges = db.roles.aggregate([
  { $match:{ _id:{ $in: user.roles} } },
  { $unwind: "$privileges" },
  { $group:{ _id: null, $push:{ "forAllRoles": "$privileges" } }
]}
```

which should result in a result document  like

```
{ _id: null, forAllRoles:[
    "adminService:*:*",  
    "someService:someAction:someInstance"
  ]
}
```

Checking a permission now becomes easy

```
var permission_needed = "adminService:*:*"

if(user_privileges.forAllRoles.indexOf(permission_needed) > -1){
  console.log("Yay, admin!");
  doSomeAdminStuff();
} else {
  console.log("Don't you dare again, user!");
}
```

Since we lookup the privileges by `roles._id`, which is indexed, the aggregation should be pretty efficient, because we limit the documents to only very few before processing.

If you want to add a permission to a role, this is straightforward

```
db.roles.update(
  { _id: "roleName" },
  { $addToSet: { privileges: [ "otherService:*:someInstance" ] } }
)
```

hth

Comment: that's great. what if I want to add a user with role "admin"? how can I check if "admin" is a valid role?

Comment: Erm, for your first question: that's a simple update to the users document. For the check: `db.roles.find({_id:"admin"},{_id:1})` isn't enough?

Comment: That works, but it needs another query to the database before inserting, right? Then it causes  two network delay in order to finish an inserting operation. Can we do this check on the database server? Just like the foreign key of SQL. Or can we write some validation functions on database?

Comment: @MatthewMa No stored procedures, no triggers, no joins, no referential integrity *on the server side*. And usually those are just things that move logic where it simply does not belong to: the data storage. Keep the logic where it belongs and is easy to update, manage and review: the code. You either assign known (read: formerly loaded) roles to a user. Or, If a user gets an invalid role, no permissions are assigned to said role, so no harm is done.

Comment: Make sense! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Since you get your index of _id for free, you should reference a user to a role _id

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("55f5128e6e5daa295293e31e"),
    name: "admin"
},
{
    _id: ObjectId("55f5128e6e5daa295293e31f"),
    "name":"user"
}
```

and assign privileges on a per user basis

```
{
    "name":"user1",
    "role":ObjectId("55f5128e6e5daa295293e31e"),
    "privileges":[]
}
```

even better yet, get rid of the roles collection

```
{
    "name":"user1",
    "role": "admin",
    "privileges":[]
}
```

or

```
{
    "name":"user1",
    "role": {
        "type": "admin",
        "additionaField": "value"
    },
    "privileges":[]
}
```

EDIT:

Chris Ma "what if I have 1k users with role "admin", now I want to add a privilege for all the admins. Then I have to edit 1k users. Right? Do we have a better solution?"

If you can imagine, the solution would be the same:

Collection "roles"

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("55f5128e6e5daa295293e31e"),
    name: "admin",
    my1KUpdate: "value"
}
```

Comment: what if I have 1k users with role "admin", now I want to add a privilege for all the admins. Then I have to edit 1k users. Right? Do we have a better solution?

Comment: Removing roles collection doesn't seem right - As a user-admin (who assigns privileges) I'd want a list of available roles to choose from.

Comment: It depends, however, 9 out of 10 times it's the right thing to do. You have 16 mb per document, if you think you'll exceed it, then separate them out. If you need to query the collection independently from the other (i.e. here it's not explicit why that should be the case), then you should have two. Since there is no obvious need to separate permission from user, consolidate them. If permission serves as a token, keep them separated. As is, with the info you provided, there is no indication you need two independent collections. SQL is not noSQL, and vice versa.

Comment: Let's say I want to insert a new user as an admin. On application side, should I query the roles collection to get the admin's _id and put it in the role field of the new user?

Comment: drivers are server side unless you're using something similar to Meteor's mini Mongo; "application side" is a little vague.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. Assume I have a node js application using the database, this is application side. I have mongod running on another machine, this is mongod server side.

Comment: if you want to create a new user, have a cache or query type of user (i.e. you'll need an index, and it would be a good idea to have the `{type: , _id: }` cached), and assign the _id to the $role of the user you want to create. For anything else where you need access to the actual role, you'll have to make an independent call to the _id of the role to get that value, unless you add it to the user document via some cron or other op.

Comment: Make sense. Thanks a lot! I'd like to see if anyone else will give other answers before accepting yours. Have a good night!

Comment: @MatthewMa just a thought; if you're in control of the client application and you screens allows roles to be picked from a list then I wonder if you really need this check anyway - just trust that role being passed to the insert is correct and if its not then there's a bug in the system that needs fixing. Also invalid roles are not going to give users extra permissions, since you're code should be checking if user is **in** a specific role, rather than **allow if doesn't have a roles**.

Comment: @ChrisMoutray I don't think it's a good idea. Making a list of roles in the application is hard-coding them. When I want to add a new role, I have to stop the application, change the code, then restart the application.

Comment: @MatthewMa no - you still have a mongo roles collection

Comment: @ChrisMoutray That makes sense. That's aug2uag's answer.